# unable to send ETH with metamask using kaleido

Tags: kaleido

I set up a Kaleido instance (quorum with raft) and connected my Metamask successfully using https://$username:$password@$rpcendpoint

Funding the account does work via Kaleido-console, but sending ETH using Metamask from the funded wallet to some other wallet fails

I can see that the transaction is signed by metamask but instantly falls into state "failed". tried different gasprices (even 0)...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of Quorum deployed within Kaleido is V2.0.2. This has some problems with EIP155 external transaction signing (as used by Metamask).
These have been resolved now in Quorum 2.1.0, and you can see the details in the release notes: https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/releases
We are currently in the process of migration testing Quorum 2.1.0 for Kaleido chains, and should be providing an updated release soon.
In the meantime, if you create a second environment with Geth + PoA you should be able to try Metamask with Kaleido, and continue to explor other Quorum features on your existing chain.
Regards, Peter